# Can't fix rails error PG::StringDataRightTruncation: ERROR: Value too long for type character varying(255)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not super familiar with rails so I would appreciate some really dumbed down answer if possible!

I'm getting the PG::StringDataRightTruncation: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(255) error. I've read online that the solution is to create a migration file and set the field to :text and then :limit => nil.

these are the steps I have taken:
1. Rails g migration
2. edited the migration file with the following code:

```
def up
    change_column :applications, :address, :text, :limit => nil
    change_column :applications, :mortAddress, :text, :limit => nil
    change_column :applications, :employer, :text, :limit => nil
    change_column :applications, :title, :text, :limit => nil
    change_column :applications, :empAddress, :text, :limit => nil
    change_column :applications, :coAddress, :text, :limit => nil
    change_column :applications, :coTitle, :text, :limit => nil
    change_column :applications, :coEmpAddress, :text, :limit => nil
    change_column :applications, :rrsp, :text, :limit => nil
    change_column :applications, :nonrrsp, :text, :limit => nil
    change_column :applications, :otherAssets, :text
  end

  def down
    change_column :applications, :address, :string
    change_column :applications, :mortAddress, :string
    change_column :applications, :employer, :string
    change_column :applications, :title, :string
    change_column :applications, :empAddress, :string
    change_column :applications, :coAddress, :string
    change_column :applications, :coTitle, :string
    change_column :applications, :coEmpAddress, :string
    change_column :applications, :rrsp, :string
    change_column :applications, :nonrrsp, :string
    change_column :applications, :otherAssets, :string
  end
end
```

3. rake db:migrate

I have also tried doing removing the :limit => nil for field :otherAssets as you can see from the code. however this is still not working.

Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: Can you post the error messages?

Comment: Are you modifying and inspecting the same database? E.g. `development`, or `test`?

Comment: As an aside, I would recommend not using the word "applications" or "application" as a model, variable or column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks everyone. I figured out what the problem was. I didn't run heroku run db:migrate!!!!

problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ChangeColumnType < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN address      TYPE text USING (address::text)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN mortAddress  TYPE text USING (mortAddress::text)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN employer     TYPE text USING (employer::text)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN title        TYPE text USING (title::text)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN empAddress   TYPE text USING (empAddress::text)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN coAddress    TYPE text USING (coAddress::text)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN coTitle      TYPE text USING (coTitle::text)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN coEmpAddress TYPE text USING (coEmpAddress::text)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN rrsp         TYPE text USING (rrsp::text)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN nonrrsp      TYPE text USING (nonrrsp::text)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN otherAssets  TYPE text USING (otherAssets::text)'
  end

  def down
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN address      TYPE string USING (address::string)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN mortAddress  TYPE string USING (mortAddress::string)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN employer     TYPE string USING (employer::string)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN title        TYPE string USING (title::string)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN empAddress   TYPE string USING (empAddress::string)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN coAddress    TYPE string USING (coAddress::string)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN coTitle      TYPE string USING (coTitle::string)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN coEmpAddress TYPE string USING (coEmpAddress::string)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN rrsp         TYPE string USING (rrsp::string)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN nonrrsp      TYPE string USING (nonrrsp::string)'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE applications ALTER COLUMN otherAssets  TYPE string USING (otherAssets::string)'
  end
end
```